# PHP Not displaying

Tags: php, html

So I am developing a webpage and I am starting to dig into PHP. I went to WS3 schools and looked at the example. I copied it over to an html document. When I double clicked on it and it opened in chrome the PHP would not show up.

Here is the example code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
<body>

    <?php
    echo "My first PHP script!";
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you closed the html tags?

Comment: are you accessing your file through a server with php support?

Comment: your file needs a `.php` extension. (Instead of `.html`)

Comment: You need a PHP server to render the php tags. It would not work out of the box

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: it looks like the code got all screwed up when i pasted it. The html markup is ok. i closed all the tags: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

  <?php
  echo "My first PHP script!";
  ?>

 </body>
</html>

Comment: Ok thanks for the notification on ws3. I was using because in highschool that what the teacher used. I guess that shows how back our tech department it. Better contact them and let them know not to use ws3.

Comment: see this one: http://www.phptherightway.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a functioning web server that can run PHP in order to be able to parse PHP files.

Just writing PHP and opening the resulting HTML file in the browser won't do.

Have a look at quick local environment such as **[XAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)** or **[WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)**.

Comment: since PHP 5.4 you don't need to install apache and struggle with its configuration, you can just run `php -S localhost:8080` in webroot directory of project

Comment: @lupatus: That's *still* not 100% recommended, mainly because you want your local environment to be closer to the one your live server would probably eventually be using.

Comment: I agree that for real project its not the best way, but for 'hello world' its enough ;)

Comment: @lupatus: Sure, but I wouldn't want him to get too comfortable with that workflow. Even setting up a basic server using XAMP is considered "bad practice", the ideal would be to manually insteall Apache/Nginx, PHP, MySQL, and configure everything properly.

Comment: I just set up WAMP and that seems to run fine. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

PHP cannot be directly rendered by the browser. It needs to be interpreted by a server first. For eg: `apache`.

If you are on windows using something like WAMP, as suggested by Madara, would help

If you are on Linux, install apache

Answer (score 0):

To learn php you need to set up local server:

1. Install XAMMP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)
2. Thne run Apache Server
3. Put script in htdocs
4. Point your browser to http : // localhost

Or just use online service like
http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 0):

Type in the the terminal/console when your navigated into your scripts directory:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

And then go to http://localhost:8080 in your browser